# "Unconnected" async socket prevents application shutdown

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous

I wrote a small c# class to check for TCP connectivity (connection to TCP socket succeeds), using BeginConnect(). It appears to work well, IF the endpoint in question is available and the TCP session is actually connected.

However, when the endpoint is not listening and the connection times out, something weird happens: The class keeps "hanging" for about 15 to 20 seconds. Which coincides with the default timeout value.

However, I call socket.Close() when the timeout triggers - Which is said by MSDN to cancel all async operations.

Why does the class prevent the application from shutting down, when the connection does not succeed? What am I doing wrong?

```
    public class CheckTCP
{
    #region "Member Variables"

        // socket connect timeout value
        private int _timeout = 2000;

        // check complete event
        public event EventHandler<CheckCompletedEventArgs> CheckCompleted;

        // perform TCP connect check
        public void PerformCheck(EndPoint Socket)
        {
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.Me = this;
            state.WorkSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            state.TimeoutTimer = new Timer();
            state.TimeoutTimer.Interval = _timeout;
            state.TimeoutTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => timeout_elapsed(sender, e, state);
            state.TimeoutTimer.Start();
            state.WorkSocket.SendTimeout = _timeout;
            state.WorkSocket.ReceiveTimeout = _timeout;
            state.WorkSocket.BeginConnect(Socket, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), state);
        }

        // connection callback
        private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
            state.TimeoutTimer.Stop();
            state.TimeoutTimer.Dispose();

            CheckCompletedEventArgs ea = new CheckCompletedEventArgs();

            if (state.WorkSocket.Connected)
            {
                state.WorkSocket.EndConnect(ar);
                state.WorkSocket.Close();
                ea.Success = true;
                state.Me.OnCheckCompleted(ea);
            }
            else
            {
                ea.Success = false;
                state.Me.OnCheckCompleted(ea);
            }

            state.WorkSocket.Dispose();
            state.Me = null;
        }

        // timeout callback
        private void timeout_elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e, StateObject state)
        {
            state.TimeoutTimer.Stop();
            state.WorkSocket.Close();
        }
    #endregion

        // raiseevent helper
        protected virtual void OnCheckCompleted(CheckCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // raise the event
            EventHandler<CheckCompletedEventArgs> handler = CheckCompleted;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        // checkcompleted event args class
        public class CheckCompletedEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public bool Success { set; get; }
        }

        // async state object
        public class StateObject
        {
            public EndPoint EndpointSocket { set; get; }
            public Socket WorkSocket { set; get; }
            public Timer TimeoutTimer { set; get; }
            public CheckTCP Me { set; get; }
        }

}
```

Comment: When I try your code it doesn't block. Do you have anything else that might interfere with the closing of the application?

Comment: Nothing else. The application is just a test app which does nothing else than create an instance of the class and calling CheckTCP(). The funny thing is, application exits normally when I test an IP:port that connects. It just hangs (application window closes, but devenv does not return from debugging) for about 20 seconds after I did a check on a nonresponding IP:port.

Comment: I might add that I'm developing on a Windows 7 64bit machine.

Comment: I found out that the "hanging" only occurs when trying to connect the socket to a firewalled port, that is a port that will not reply with an ICMP error message or an RST. Is there any way around this, perhaps using a socket option?